# IE 8 HTML Print Page Issue

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, print-preview

Having some trouble with the print preview in IE 8 ( Please note I am using the original IE 8 instead of IE 9 and changing to 8 ).

The problem is that when a user wants to "print preview" a page the previews layout is a lot different from what you see on the site itself.

Here is a screen shot of what a print preview looks like with the above issue:

[image]

This should look like this:

[image]

I have checked Google and cannot see any recommended fixes available for this issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: Without any html/css examples, your question cannot be answered. It's most likely a positioning bug, possibly in a @media=print stylesheet

Comment: are you using html5shiv? If so, make sure you're on the latest version, because older versions caused issues with printing.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry guys - have fixed the issue - Was regarding the doctype.

On page load the site would render in IE 8 with IE 7 standards *Facepalm...